# Convert time zone from EST to UTC using R base functions

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, timezone, posixct

I need to change my time zone from EST to UTC using the base R functions. I wrote this code but the problem is that although during the daylight saving time the time difference between these two time zones should be 4 hours, the function does not take it into account. Therefore, during the whole year the time difference equals to 5. My dataset is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjlmq9m0scr6x6l/data.csv?dl=0).

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
data1 <- data
attributes(data1$time)$tzone
data1$time <- as.POSIXct(data1$time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="EST")
attributes(data1$time)$tzone
attr(data1$time, "tzone") <- "UTC"
attributes(data1$time)$tzone
```

Comment: please do not share data by uploading it somewhere. rather provide some sample data right at StackOverflow, e.g. with `dput(head(your_data))`

Comment: Try using `tz = "US/Eastern"` or `tz = "America/New_York"` instead of `tz="EST"`.

Comment: I think your `data.csv` file link points to data _after_ your `colnames(.)` reassignment, right? Otherwise I don't know whay `nyisodata` is (nor its column names).

Comment: Further, you say *"the time difference equals to 5"*, based on what? When I read the data, `time` ranges from `"2015-01-01 00:00:00"` to `"2022-12-31 23:00:00"`, which suggests nine full years of hourly data. And since neither TZ nor offset are included in the raw file, it's whatever you load it as.

Comment: @r2evans. Thanks. Sorry, file link points to data after my `colnames(.)`.

Comment: @r2evans I mean "Eastern Standard Time (EST), when observing standard time (autumn/winter), are five hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC−05:00). Eastern Daylight Time (EDT), when observing daylight saving time (spring/summer), are four hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC−04:00)."

Comment: @r2evans My dataset is [New York's electricity](https://www.nyiso.com/) demand.

Comment: I understand time zone. Your data doesn't have it, so I don't understand how it can be wrong. It would be very helpful for you to show precisely where it is wrong and how you know it is wrong, without lecturing about daylight savings time, perhaps.

Comment: @r2evans. Thanks. it solved the problem. The problem with my code was that during the whole year the difference between two time zone was 5 hours. However, during the daylight saving time, the difference should be 4 hours.

Comment: What solved the problem?  If you have a solution, you can post it as an answer to your own question (indeed it's encouraged).

Answer (score 0):

Using `tz = "EST"` means you are specifying Eastern **standard** time, which is only active in autumn/winter.  As indicated by @r2evans, `tz = "US/Eastern"` or `tz = "America/New_York"` specifies that the time should switch between EST and EDT (Eastern daylight time) on the appropriate dates.